# can't conda install chromedriver

Tags: python, anaconda

So i'm working on a little project where i scrape yahoo news comments.

There has a error when I try to install  chromedriver.

I wonder that I made some mistake,
I would be appreciate it if someone could tell me.

```
(base) PS C:\Users\aaa> conda install chromedriver
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - chromedriver

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

than when I downloaded the file from
<sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver>
and open the exe file,
that showed

```
Starting ChromeDriver 93.0.4577.63 (ff5c0da2ec0adeaed5550e6c7e98417dac77d98a-refs/branch-heads/4577@{#1135}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

when I run the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

that showed the error :

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19043 x86_64)
```

I wonder if the chrome version is too old.

what should I do?

Comment: you can download chromedriver form [here] <https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/>

Comment: thank you so much.
when i opened the exe that show
```
Starting ChromeDriver 93.0.4577.63 (ff5c0da2ec0adeaed5550e6c7e98417dac77d98a-refs/branch-heads/4577@{#1135}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

Comment: Be careful! Do not use the `base` environment for development, it can lead to all kinds of issues. Instead, use separate environments for each project/app.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves the problem, but I found this command [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python-chromedriver-binary)

```
 conda install -c conda-forge python-chromedriver-binary
```

EDIT:

the chrome driver requires that you specify google chrome and chromedriver paths.

first you need to download the chromedriver from [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=93.0.4577.63/), then in your python code add the paths as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = r"<YOUR_CHROME_PATH>\chrome.exe"
chrome_driver_path = r"<PATH_TO_CHROME_DRIVER>\chromedriver.exe>"

browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path, options=options)
```

Comment: yes,thank you so much.
but it still showed the error  "WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary"